# Using slicer to effect 2 different visuals in different ways

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have an order table which the bulk of my on-screen data is coming from, as well as a separate projections table and I'm trying to map my actual sales as a percentage of actual sales. My slicer for period works fine for the order table, but does not effect the projections table. I have both these tables connected to a date ref table, [Orders].[OrderDate] > [DateRef].[Date], and [Projections].[Week] > [DateRef].[Week].

I want my slier for Period (Month), which is coming from the orders table, to extract the relevant data from the orders table (which it is doing), but I also want it to simply divide the projections total by 12 when a period is selected. So if I select period 1, the projected total is projections/12, and if I select 3 months, it will be shown as projections/12 * 3.

I have tried new columns, relationships etc, but without messing up other pages on my report this is proving very difficult. The projections table is separate from the rest of my data and unfortunately the format cannot be changed to add other relationships.

Is it possible to have a slicer effect 2 different tables differently? Can I do this using DAX/measure?

Comment: Where is your sample data and expected output?